# Using apache kafka in SSL mode

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I'm trying to set up kafka in SSL [1-way] mode. I've gone through the official documentation and successfully generated the certificates. I'll note down the behavior for 2 different cases. This setup has only one broker and one zookeeper.

#### Case-1: Inter-broker communication - Plaintext

Relevant entries in my `server.properties` file are as follows:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, SSL://localhost:9093
ssl.keystore.location=/Users/xyz/home/ssl/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=****
ssl.key.password=****
```

I've added a `client-ssl.properties` in kafka config dir with following entries:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/Users/xyz/home/ssl/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=****
```

If I put `bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093` or `bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092` in my `config/producer.properties` file, my console-producers/consumers work fine. Is that the intended behavior? If yes, then why? Because I'm specifically trying to connect to `localhost:9093` from producer/consumer in SSL mode.

#### Case-2: Inter-broker communication - SSL

Relevant entries in my `server.properties` file are as follows:

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
listeners=SSL://localhost:9093
ssl.keystore.location=/Users/xyz/home/ssl/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=****
ssl.key.password=****
```

My `client-ssl.properties` file remains the same. I put `bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093` in `producer.properties` file. Now, none of my producer/consumer can connect to kafka. I get the following msg:

```
WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

What am I doing wrong?

In all these cases I'm using the following commands to start producers/consumers:

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic test --producer.config ../config/client-ssl.properties
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic test --consumer.config ../config/client-ssl.properties
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the common names (CN) in your certificates match your hostname.
SSL protocol verify CN against hostname. I guess here you should have CN=localhost.
I had a similar issue and that's how I fixed it.

Comment: If CN was wrong, I shouldn't have been able to connect in SSL mode with security.inter.broker.protocol in PLAINTEXT right?

Comment: Well I could connect in SSL mode with plaintext inter broker protocol. It looks like CN is checked against hostname only when security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL

Comment: Recently I had to repeat the same stuffs for my current project and I found out from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614443/kafka-ssl-handshake-failed-issue) by @Venkateswararao T that when it asks you to provide the first name and last name, it has to be `localhost`. I used the ssl-generator from [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools)

Answer (score 2):

One important information regarding this: The behavior where the CN has to be equal to the hostname can be deactivated, by adding the following line to server.properties:

```
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

The default value for this setting is set to https, which ultimately activates the host to CN verification. This is the default since Kafka 2.0.

I've successfully tested a SSL setup (just on the broker side though) with the following properties:

```
    ############################ SSL Config #################################
    ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/kafka.truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password=TrustStorePassword
    ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/kafka.server.keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password=KeyStorePassword
    ssl.key.password=PrivateKeyPassword
    security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
    listeners=SSL://localhost:9093
    advertised.listeners=SSL://127.0.0.1:9093
    ssl.client.auth=required
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

You can also find a Shell script to generate SSL certificates (with key- and truststores) alongside some documentation in this github project: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools

Answer (score 0):

Well, both the given answers point out to the right direction, but some more details need to be added to end this confusion.

I generated the certs using this bash [script](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools/blob/master/kafka-generate-ssl-automatic.sh) from confluent, and when I looked inside the file, it made sense. I'm pasting the relevant section here:

```
echo "     NOTE: currently in Kafka, the Common Name (CN) does not need to be the FQDN of"
echo "     this host. However, at some point, this may change. As such, make the CN"
echo "     the FQDN. Some operating systems call the CN prompt 'first / last name'"
```

There you go. When you're generating the certs, make sure to put `localhost` (or FQDN) when it asks for first / last name. Do remember that you need to use the same endpoint to expose the broker.